# Submitting Cases on a Website

Tags: civicase

We installed CiviCRM 4.6.5 on our Joomla site recently and enabled CiviCase. What is the best method for allowing site visitors to submit a form that becomes a case? We can't seem to find the obvious answer, if there is one.

Answer (score 6):

Drupal Webform-Integration offers a robust solution for this. Unfortunately there is no equivalent for Joomla.

Answer (score 4):

Sans-webforms, the simplest solution might be to create a CiviCRM [profile form](http://book.civicrm.org/user/organising-your-data/profiles), and then write a small amount of custom code in a [hook](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Hook+Reference) which uses the [api](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Using+the+API) to open a new case.

Answer (score 0):

We have done this extensively in a project with CiviCRM 4.4 and used Drupal Webform - CiviCRM integration module and loved it.